# Get запрос TIdHTTP в парсере, начинает получать ответ сервера HTTP/1.1 204 No Content

Tags: delphi, get, http, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Пишу парсер друзей из odnoklassniki.ru. Суть - программа залогинивается под аккаунтом, потом в отдельном потоке из списка с ID'ами пользователей выводит в текстовое поле ID'ы их друзей.  Так вот, через штук 5-7 пропарсенных профилей GET запрос начинает возвращать только пустоту (''), (когда возвращает пустоту - ответ сервера "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content")  или просто поток завершается.

Есть функция, которая по ID человека получает список его друзей, она действует примерно по такому алгоритму:
- Заходит на страницу друзей человека (GET http://odnoklassniki.ru/ID человека/friends)
- Парсит страницу, сохраняет кол-во друзей в переменную
- Разбив кол-во друзей на страницы, в цикле GET (на сайте запросы с помощью ajax) запросами получает ссылки на друзей

Так вот, программа по списку ID'ов пользователей, друзей которых нужно спарсить проходит циклом с упомянутой выше функцией, и где то после 15-20 круга цикла запрос который получает кол-во друзей (шаг 1 в алгоритме) начинает до конца возвращать "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content". Т.е. если есть у нас список из 40 человек, друзей 10 первых она спарсит, а дальше "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content".

Помогите выявить проблему. Сразу извинюсь, код местами безобразный т.к. программа на стадии отладки.
Delphi 7, Indy 9.

[Скачать исходники (rghost)](http://rghost.ru/36286274)

Comment: Решил перенести работу с сетью на Synapse, по результату отпишусь.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле при подобном обращении может быть банальная защита от DOS, например, пауза выдачи для вашего IP/сессии.

Может, у вас что-то получится с использованием API? Для получения списка друзей вообще все [банально](http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/display/ok/REST+API+-+friends.get):

```
Request : /friends/get?application_key=[Application Key]&sig=[Signature]&session_key=[Session Key]

Ответ JSON:
["CAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","GGAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"]
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую заюзать API, но все же, как обнаружить проблему в моем случае? Насчет защиты - пробывал ставить таймауты при 204 коде, бесполезно.

Comment: А не пробовали сделать обход через прокси, меняя их на каждые 10 записей, например?

Comment: Сейчас попробую так сделать. А по поводу API - вариант отпадает, нужно чтобы программа была подтверждена их компанией, для взаимодействия с API как я понял.

Comment: Не помогают прокси.

Comment: Будет времени больше, смогу посмотреть детальнее, сейчас пока идей нету.

Answer (score 0):

Перенес на Synapse, ошибки ушли.